# Idiomatic Vector Algebra in Haskell

Tags: haskell

As a way to practice with the vector library in Haskell, I'm trying to rewrite a Nelder-Mead minimization algorithm I had previously written in C. 
So far I've been having a bit of trouble translating some vector operations idiomatically.

For instance, consider a function which finds the centroid of n vectors out of a list of n+1 (filtering away one index),

In C, this can be written as

```c
static void get_centroid(double **s, int n, int iz,
                         double *C)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
    if (i != iz) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        C[j] += s[i][j];
    }
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    C[j] /= n;
}
```

I tried translating this into Haskell, and ended up with the following

```haskell
import Data.Vector
import qualified Data.Vector as V

type Node = Vector Double

type Simplex = Vector Node

centroid :: Simplex -> Int -> Node
centroid s iz = V.map (/ (fromIntegral $ V.length s)) $ V.zipWith (-) v (s ! iz) 
    where v = V.foldl go V.empty s 
        where go a b = V.zipWith (+) a b
```

I find this code quite inelegant, as it doesn't capture the essence of the vector algebra that's happening (and is also more inefficient since I'm adding and subtracting S[iz]).

One solution would be to implement some kind of vector space typeclass or use a more specific linear algebra library, but since those are such common operations I was wondering if there's a more idiomatic 'straight' solution.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Data.Vector` for this? A more specific library is almost certainly the way to go. But if you want to try it with these vectors, you should 1. Switch to the "unboxed" versions for speed, and 2. look into vector slicing operations to skip a row/column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd start with a +1 for dfeuer; a more specific library will almost certainly be both cleaner and more efficient.

However, if what you are looking for is a more idiomatic implementation of your `centroid` function, I like this one:

```
centroid' :: Simplex -> Int -> Node
centroid' s iz = let t = foldl1 (V.zipWith (+)) (V.drop iz s)
                     n = fromIntegral (V.length t - 1)
                 in V.map (/ n) t
```

One general comment on your version: it's very easy to create "write-only" Haskell code. There is so much going on in your first line that it is difficult to parse. Your `where` block is step in the right direction, but I'd go even further to break out the conceptual components.

Also, [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/). I didn't know there existed a function `drop`, but I knew that if it existed, it took an `Int` and a `Vector` onto a new `Vector`. Hoogle doesn't index `Vector`, but the API for vector is very similar to the API for lists. I searched for "[a] -> Int -> [a]" and "Int -> [a] -> [a]" and found `drop`.

([Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) does index `Vector`, so search for "Int -> Vector a -> Vector a" works there)

Comment: Thanks! This is the kind of answer I was looking for. I think the foldl and map capture the essence of each vector operation, and I can imagine how this generalises to more complex algorithms.